Create Primitive Array from Class Array
I am a C# developer in my day job and I'm working on a side project in Kotlin while trying to learn the language.  I am consolidating ArrayLists into a single ArrayList using a class like this.
class Person(val id: Int, val name: String){}

I have taken multiple lists like this
private var listOfPeopleIds: ArrayList<Int> = ArrayList()
private var listOfNames: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()

to
private var listOfPeople: ArrayList<Person> = ArrayList()

but in one part of the code I need to break out the consolidated ArrayList back to a list of names for some underlying code.  In C# I'd use LINQ like
var names = peopleList.Select(p => p.name).ToList();

but I'm having a hard time finding functionality like this in Kotlin.

In your case: var names = listOfPeople.map { it.name}

Thank you!  I knew I was just missing something
